# Error when trying to create or edit a job step in SQL Server "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I am using

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) 
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: )
```

The recent things I have done was creating a job that restores databases dynamically from a path, ran it and disabled it.

Afterwards, when I tried to add a new step I got this error:

> The system cannot find the file specified

I can't find any errors in the SQL Server logs.

I am able to create jobs with T-SQL and able to run them.

The other similar question on stack overflow are not relevant to my issue.

Why am I getting this error suddenly?

This is the error copied from management studio:

> The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.get_LogProviderInfos()
> at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DTSExecUI.Controls.LoggingCtrl..ctor(IDTSExecViewManager treePanel)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.DTSJobSubSystemDefinition.InitializeControls()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.DTSJobSubSystemDefinition..ctor(CDataContainer dataContainer, IMessageBoxProvider messageProvider)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepSubSystems.CreateJobStepSubSystemSsis(AgentSubSystem agentSubSystem, CDataContainer dataContainer, JobStepData data, IMessageBoxProvider messageProvider)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepSubSystems.CreateJobStepSubSystem(AgentSubSystem agentSubSystem, CDataContainer dataContainer, JobStepData data, IMessageBoxProvider messageProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepSubSystems..ctor(CDataContainer dataContainer, JobStepData data, IMessageBoxProvider messageProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.get_SubSystems()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.FilterStepCombo(DatabaseEngineEdition engineEdition)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.InitializeStepCombo()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.InitializeData()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.OnInitialization()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.SetView(Int32 index, TreeNode node)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.SelectCurrentNode()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.InitializeUI(ViewSwitcherTreeView treeView, ISqlControlCollection viewsHolder, Panel rightPane)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.LaunchForm.InitializeForm(XmlDocument doc, IServiceProvider provider, ISqlControlCollection control)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.LaunchForm..ctor(ISqlControlCollection control, IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobSteps.OnDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseButtonDoubleClickedEventArgs args)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.Grid.GridControl.OnMouseButtonDoubleClicked(HitTestResult htArea, Int64 nRowIndex, Int32 nColIndex, Rectangle rCellRect, MouseButtons btn, GridButtonArea headerArea)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlManagerUIDlgGrid.OnMouseButtonDoubleClicked(HitTestResult htArea, Int64 rowIndex, Int32 colIndex, Rectangle cellRect, MouseButtons btn, GridButtonArea headerArea)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.Grid.GridControl.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.Grid.GridControl.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.RunningFormsTable.RunningFormsTableImpl.ThreadStarter.StartThread()
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.get_LogProviderInfos()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.get_LogProviderInfos()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a problem with SQL log configuration. You might somewhere have a path configured that no longer exists (or is no longer available from the server service's perspective). [Look into this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-error-log?view=sql-server-ver15) and check all logging settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was some problem with SSMS.
I only noticed it when trying to edit a job step on another server.
When opening a new instance of SSMS, everything worked fine.